# What will be the inverse of $x^x$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

The question says -

> Let $f(x) = x^x$, $x  \in (0,\infty)$ and let $g(x)$ be the inverse of $f(x)$, then $g'(x)$ must be?

I tried taking log on both sides of the given equation but I get stuck. I cannot find any other way to proceed. Try answering this question on a high school level.

Comment: This function is not invertible. Try something else.

Comment: @Tony It is invertible e.g. because it is strictly increasing.

Comment: @Arnav Mahajan I know that, but for this particular question, you don't need to find that. Also, you may not be knowing the theory needed behind this eg Lambert function etc. This is a standard high school problem.

Comment: My upvoted comment is incorrect. I assumed $x \ge 1$ which is not true. It is actually not invertible in this interval.

Comment: @Tony So how must I start to work upon this problem?

Comment: You aren't aske to find the inverse (which is... what it is...) you are asked to find the derivative of the the inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^x= e^{x\ln x}$. So $f'(x) = e^{x\ln x}[x\frac 1x + \ln x]=(1+\ln x)f(x)$.

let $g(x) = f^{-1}(x)$.

Then $x = f\circ g(x)$.

So $1 = \frac {dx}{dx} = f'(g(x))*g'(x)$

So $g'(x) = \frac 1{f'(g(x))} = \frac {1}{(1+\ln g(x))f(g(x))}=\frac 1{(1+\ln g(x))x}$

...

But as pointed out by others, $f(x)$ is not invertable for all $x$.  This will hold true if $x >\frac 1e$.

.....

Also note.  The question did not ask us to, and we do not need to, find an expression of $g(x)$.  It's *enough* to simply say $g(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ for $x > \frac 1e$.  That is well defined and understood.

Comment: Yes this is the answer given. Thanks fleablood.

Answer (score 1):

I would likely use Charlie's approach since it gives you a more explicit answer, but there's an alternative approach you can take, which is handled in generality [here](https://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth251/cq/Stage6/Lesson/inverseDeriv.html).

Essentially, let $f$ be invertible with inverse $f^{-1}$. Then

$$\frac{d}{dx} f^{-1} = \frac{1}{(f' \circ f^{-1})(x)}$$

However, it turns out this function is not invertible unless you restrict the domain to $(1/e, \infty)$, as you can see from the graph:

[image]